# Recursive CTE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Union all function is not working inside the Recursive CTE...?

```
with CTE_Manager(id,manager,man_id,[Level])
as
(
    select id,manager,man_id,1
    from manager
    where man_id is null

union all

    select a.id,a.manager,a.man_id,b.[Level]+1
    from manager a
    join CTE_Manager b
    on b.man_id= a.id
)
select a.manager,ISNULL(a.manager,'SUPER BOSS'),b.Level
from CTE_Manager a
join CTE_Manager b
on a.man_id=b.id
```

Actually i am getting the output:

I am retrieving the value before the union all function.I have to get all the values from the recursive CTE.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you mean with "union all is not working"? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Show us some sample data and the expected output (edit your question, don't post that in a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on clause in your join is the wrong way around. It should be b.id = a.man_id.

What you have done is selected all managers that don't have a manager and then tried to find their manager. When what I suspect you want is all of their subordinates.